# How to show the data on webpage after submit in java servlets?

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

here is the picture of html page now i want that entered should appear when i enter register button.The file is connected to mysql and the entered data is shown whenever i register.Here is the link to picture.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTRfP.png

Here is the code of java file.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String name = request.getParameter("name");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String pass = request.getParameter("pass");
    try{

    //loading drivers for mysql
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

//creating connection with the database 
      Connection  conn=DriverManager.getConnection
                 ("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/form","root","xxxx");

    PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement
              ("insert into Student values(?,?,?)");

    ps.setString(1, name);
    ps.setString(2, email);
    ps.setString(3, pass);
    int i=ps.executeUpdate();

      if(i>0)
      {
        out.println("you are successfully regitered");
      }
      String query = "SELECT * FROM student";

  // create the java statement
  Statement st = conn.createStatement();

  // execute the query, and get a java resultset
  ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);

  // iterate through the java resultset
  while (rs.next())
  {
                rs.getString("name");
                rs.getString("email");
                rs.getString("pass");


    // print the results
    System.out.format("%s, %s, %s\n", name, email, pass);
     System.out.print("name: " + name);
     System.out.print(", email: " + email);
     System.out.print(", pass: " + pass);

  }

  st.close();

    }
    catch(Exception se)
    {
        se.printStackTrace();
    }


  }
```

I have tried adding the links of the html pages in the println function but that doesn't work so please suggest.

Comment: You should use the Writer you are getting from the response object to create the HTML code. This is displayed on client side after submitting. There you can include the request parameters.

Comment: use request.setAttribute("myObjectName", myObject) 
 to set your object as return attribute and use request.getRequestDispatcher("/mypage.jsp").forward(request, response) to return to mypage.jsp

Comment: whats the writer?

Comment: i don't have any jsp file @YogeshHShenoy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you want to show a confirmation message when data is successfully added. 
When you make a call to a url, a request is created with all the headers and parameters and sent to the server. In your case, the servlet container catches it and processes it and sends the response back.

Writing to the response can be done by:

```
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
out.println("message to return");
```

However, this does not show the message in the webpage. You have to do that explicitly. You can do it in 2 ways.
1 using ajax.
2 using jsp.

USING AJAX
Make an ajax call to the url and process the response in a way that you want. Using libraries like jQuery make it easy.

USING JSP
In the `doGet()` or `doPost()` methods, add this line in the end

```
request.setAttribute("message", "my message");
request.getRequestDispatcher(URL).forward(request, response);
```

This redirects to the specified `URL` with the attribute set. Usually, it is a jsp page where you read the attribute and display it however you want.

Comment: I still don't get it.i don't have any jsp so should i create it?

Comment: @vinaysingh if u dont have jsp page you should use the first method. dont use the second one

Comment: @YogeshHShenoy i dont have a jsp page

Comment: @vinaysingh instead of doing a form submit on the click of the register button, make an ajax call to the servlet. Then from the response you get display the message however you want.